# Serving a different JS file from a server depending on the number of times a URL is visited by a client?

Tags: javascript, cron, server

I've an web app that injects a server based myjavascriptfile.js file from my server, using jQuery AJAX GET request. Currently, this GET request is called every time the client visits https://www.google.co.uk.

However I'd like to be able to send mysecondjavascriptfile.js file to the client, if the client has gone to https://www.google.co.uk more that 10 times.

Do you have any ways I can do this?

Comment: You're going to need a tracking mechanism for this first. Explore cookies for counting their visits. And then include that cookie value in a header somewhere in the requests. the server side is easy then.

Comment: Thank you! Could you briefly explain how a cookie would enable me to tell if the page has been visited 10 times? I assume it won't create 10 individual cookies?

Comment: On first visit, document.cookie('visits=1'); Every time someone visits your site, check for the instance of that cookie, read it if it exists and do another assignment increasing it by 1. Read cookies by saying var x = document.cookie;

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do, is to persist the hits the client do to the site. I think `SessionStorage` could help here:

```
sessionStorage.counter = ++(sessionStorage.counter) || 0;

var sources = {
    lessThanTen : 'http://yourscript.com/lessthan10hits.js',
    moreThanTen : 'http://yourscript.com/morethan10hits.js'
}
var script = document.createElement('script');

if(sessionStorage.counter >= 10){
    script.src = sources.moreThanTen;
} else {
    script.src = sources.lessThanTen;
}

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

This is of course a client-side verification of the hit. You could implement a server-side verification through AJAX or just serve a slightly different HTML markup after 10 requests. You'll need to use sessions (or just plain cookies) to persist them on the server-side.

AJAX verification:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = xhr.response;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
});
xhr.open('POST', 'http://www.urltocheckhits.com/hits');
xhr.send('url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname));
```

And then from Node.js (with body-parser and express-session):

```
var sources = {
    lessThanTen : 'http://yourscript.com/lessthan10hits.js',
    moreThanTen : 'http://yourscript.com/morethan10hits.js'
}
app.post('/hits', urlEncoded, function(req, res){
    if(req.body){
        var url = req.body.url;
        if(!req.session.views){
           req.session.views = { };
        }
        if(req.session.views[url]){
            req.session.views[url]++;
        } else {
            req.session.views[url] = 1; 
        }

        if(req.session.views[url] > 10){
            res.send(sources.moreThanTen);
        } else {
            res.send(sources.lessThanTen);
        }
    }
});
```

I suggest you check the documentation of [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) and [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

Note that you'll need to add CORS Headers for this (you could just as easily do it with JSONP too instead of using XHR).

Might be easier if you just serve the JS file instead of doing the AJAX call and then including the returned script. So then you could just:

```
<script src="http://onesingleurl.com/hits">
```

Caching will behave weird like this though, so that's why I favor the other approach.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I'm keen to keep things server side. What would server side verification look like?

Comment: It would depend on what are you using on your server side.

Comment: I'm using a simple node.js with express :)

Comment: Any ideas? I suppose I could pass the cookies as an object with the AJAX and store them in the database?

Comment: @O.Jan, I have updated the answer. I didn't go into much detail about `body-parser` or `express-session` because those subjects alone will take a more lengthy discussion (I really suggest to check out the documentation).

Comment: Would express sessions work if the web client was a chrome extension (i.e. not based off the node.js server)?